# python_binance websocket : How I can handle this error with web socket?

Tags: python, websocket, binance

```
from binance.client import Client
from binance import ThreadedWebsocketManager
import pandas as pd

my_api = ""
my_secret = ""

client = Client(api_key=my_api, api_secret=my_secret, tld="com", testnet=True)

twm = ThreadedWebsocketManager(api_key=my_api, api_secret=my_secret)
twm.start()


def simple_bot(msg):
    ''' define how to process incoming WebSocket messages '''

    time = pd.to_datetime(msg["E"], unit="ms")
    price = float(msg["c"])

    print("Time: {} | Price: {}".format(time, price))

    if int(price) % 10 == 0:
        order = client.create_order(symbol="BTCUSDT", side="BUY", type="MARKET", quantity=0.1)
        print("\n" + 50 * "-")
        print("Buy {} BTC for {} USDT".format(order["executedQty"], order["cummulativeQuoteQty"]))
        print(50 * "-" + "\n")

        twm.stop()

twm.start_symbol_ticker_socket(callback=simple_bot, symbol="BTCUSDT")
```

These are my codes, and when I tried to run these, I got the error like below.

****-----ERROR TEXT-----****

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 986, in _wrap_create_connection
return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1089, in create_connection
transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1119, in _create_connection_transport
await waiter
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 534, in data_received
ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 188, in feed_ssldata
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 974, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/binance/threaded_stream.py", line 56, in run
self._loop.run_until_complete(self.socket_listener())
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/binance/threaded_stream.py", line 35, in socket_listener
self._client = await AsyncClient.create(loop=self._loop, **self._client_params)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 7258, in create
await self.ping()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 7379, in ping
return await self._get('ping', version=self.PRIVATE_API_VERSION)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 7344, in _get
return await self._request_api('get', path, signed, version, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 7307, in _request_api
return await self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 7288, in _request
async with getattr(self.session, method)(uri, **kwargs) as response:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1138, in **aenter**
self._resp = await self._coro
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 535, in _request
conn = await self._connector.connect(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 542, in connect
proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 907, in _create_connection
_, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1206, in _create_direct_connection
raise last_exc
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1175, in _create_direct_connection
transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 988, in _wrap_create_connection
raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host api.binance.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)')]

**I can't understand why this is not working.
Could you help me!?
Thank you!**

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and had recently updated to python 3.10 on a Mac.

You need to go into the Applications/WhateverPythonYouAreUsing folder and click on "Install Certificates.command".

It will open a terminal and install certificates.

That fixed it for me.